# flashcards gallery with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

There is a flashcard on the second created page of the accordion. When I add a new flashcard with the + button, it is located below the first flashcard. I want to create a flashcard gallery. To navigate between cards with the previous and next buttons.

What kind of changes should I make in the `function create flashcard()` so that the added flashcards with + button appear as a slide gallery instead of one under the other?

[You can also review the same codes on CodePen](https://codepen.io/ilkerbesken/pen/poYVXLx)

[I want it to look like this after the added flashcards](https://codepen.io/ilkerbesken/pen/zYbxZzK)

```js
let currentAccordionBody;
let currentFlashcardContainer;


function openPopup() {
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "flex";
}

function closePopup() {
  document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("pageTitle").value = "";
}

function createAccordion() {
  const pageTitle = document.getElementById("pageTitle").value;

  if (pageTitle.trim() !== "") {
    const accordionContainer = document.getElementById("accordion");
    const accordionItem = document.createElement("div");
    accordionItem.className = "accordion-item";

    const accordionHeader = document.createElement("div");
    accordionHeader.className = "accordion-header";
    accordionHeader.innerText = pageTitle;
    accordionHeader.onclick = function() {
      toggleAccordion(accordionBody);
    };

    const accordionBody = document.createElement("div");
    accordionBody.className = "accordion-body";


    const subAccordionButton = document.createElement("button");
    subAccordionButton.className = "sub-accordion-button";
    subAccordionButton.innerText = "+";
    subAccordionButton.onclick = function() {
      currentAccordionBody = accordionBody;
      openSubPopup();
    };

    accordionBody.appendChild(subAccordionButton);

    const subAccordion = document.createElement("div");
    subAccordion.className = "accordion";
    subAccordion.appendChild(accordionBody);

    const flashcardContainer = document.createElement("div");
    flashcardContainer.className = "flashcard-container";


    flashcardContainer.appendChild(subAccordion);

    accordionItem.appendChild(accordionHeader);
    accordionItem.appendChild(flashcardContainer);

    accordionContainer.appendChild(accordionItem);

    // Popup'ı kapatma işlemi
    closePopup();
  } else {
    alert("Please write a Page Title.");
  }
}

function toggleAccordion(element) {
  const displayValue = (element.style.display === 'none' || element.style.display === '') ? 'block' : 'none';
  element.style.display = displayValue;
}

function openSubPopup() {
  document.getElementById("subPopup").style.display = "flex";
}

function closeSubPopup() {
  document.getElementById("subPopup").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("subPageTitle").value = "";
}

function createSubAccordion() {
  const subPageTitle = document.getElementById("subPageTitle").value;

  if (subPageTitle.trim() !== "") {
    const subAccordionItem = document.createElement("div");
    subAccordionItem.className = "accordion-item";

    const subAccordionHeader = document.createElement("div");
    subAccordionHeader.className = "accordion-header";
    subAccordionHeader.innerText = subPageTitle;
    subAccordionHeader.onclick = function() {
      toggleAccordion(subAccordionBody);
    };

    const subAccordionBody = document.createElement("div");
    subAccordionBody.className = "accordion-body";

    const flashcardContainer = document.createElement("div");
    flashcardContainer.className = "flashcard-container";

    const flashcardAddButton = document.createElement("button");
    flashcardAddButton.className = "add-flashcard-button";
    flashcardAddButton.innerText = "+";
    flashcardAddButton.onclick = function() {
      currentAccordionBody = subAccordionBody;
      currentFlashcardContainer = flashcardContainer;
      createFlashcard();
    };

    flashcardContainer.appendChild(subAccordionBody);
    flashcardContainer.appendChild(flashcardAddButton);

    subAccordionItem.appendChild(subAccordionHeader);
    subAccordionItem.appendChild(flashcardContainer);

    currentAccordionBody.appendChild(subAccordionItem);

    // Popup'ı kapatma işlemi
    closeSubPopup();
  } else {
    alert("Please write a SubPage Title.");
  }
}

function createFlashcard() {
  const flashcardContainer = currentFlashcardContainer;
  const flashcard = document.createElement("div");
  flashcard.className = "flashcard";

  const flashcardInner = document.createElement("div");
  flashcardInner.className = "flashcard-inner";

  const flashcardFront = document.createElement("div");
  flashcardFront.className = "flashcard-front";
  flashcardFront.innerText = "Front";
  flashcardFront.onclick = function() {
    currentFlashcard = flashcard;
    openEditPopup();
  };

  const flashcardBack = document.createElement("div");
  flashcardBack.className = "flashcard-back";
  flashcardBack.innerText = "Back";
  flashcardBack.onclick = function() {
    currentFlashcard = flashcard;
    openEditPopup();
  };

  flashcardInner.appendChild(flashcardFront);
  flashcardInner.appendChild(flashcardBack);

  flashcard.appendChild(flashcardInner);

  const flashcardEditButton = document.createElement("button");
  flashcardEditButton.className = "add-flashcard-button";
  flashcardEditButton.innerText = "+";
  flashcardEditButton.onclick = function() {
    currentFlashcard = flashcard;
    openEditPopup();
  };

  flashcardContainer.insertBefore(flashcard, flashcardContainer.lastChild);

  if (flashcardContainer.classList.contains("accordion-body")) {
    flashcardContainer.insertBefore(flashcardEditButton, flashcardContainer.lastChild);
  }

  closeSubPopup(); // Alt sayfa popup'ını kapatma işlemi
}

function openEditPopup() {
  document.getElementById("editPopup").style.display = "flex";
}

function closeEditPopup() {
  document.getElementById("editPopup").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("frontContent").value = "";
  document.getElementById("backContent").value = "";
}

function updateFlashcardContent() {
  const frontContent = document.getElementById("frontContent").value;
  const backContent = document.getElementById("backContent").value;

  if (frontContent.trim() !== "" || backContent.trim() !== "") {
    const flashcardInner = currentFlashcard.querySelector(".flashcard-inner");
    const flashcardFront = flashcardInner.querySelector(".flashcard-front");
    const flashcardBack = flashcardInner.querySelector(".flashcard-back");

    flashcardFront.innerText = frontContent.trim() !== "" ? frontContent : "Ön Yüz";
    flashcardBack.innerText = backContent.trim() !== "" ? backContent : "Arka Yüz";

    closeEditPopup();
  } else {
    alert("Please write a content.");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.popup-content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.accordion {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.accordion-item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion-header {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-body {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: none;
  /* Başlangıçta tüm gövdeleri gizle */
  z-index: 2;
}

.sub-input {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sub-accordion-button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sub-popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.sub-popup-content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flashcard-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Kartları sığdırmak için eklenen özellik */
}

.flashcard-list {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.flashcard-container .add-flashcard-button {
  position: static;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.flashcard-navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.flashcard-counter {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.add-flashcard-button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flashcard {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.flashcard-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.flashcard:hover .flashcard-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flashcard-front,
.flashcard-back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 3rem, #F0A4A4 calc(3rem), #F0A4A4 calc(3rem + 2px), transparent 1px), repeating-linear-gradient(0deg, transparent, transparent 1.5rem, #DDD 1px, #DDD calc(1.5rem + 1px));
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}

.flashcard-front {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.flashcard-back {
  background-color: #858585;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.edit-popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.edit-popup-content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.accordion-item .add-flashcard-button {
  position: static;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button onclick="openPopup()">+</button>

  <div id="popup" class="popup">
    <div class="popup-content">
      <label for="pageTitle">Page Title:</label>
      <input type="text" id="pageTitle" placeholder="Page Title">
      <button onclick="createAccordion()">Create</button>
      <button onclick="closePopup()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="container">
  <div id="popup" class="popup">
    <div class="popup-content">
      <label for="pageTitle">Page title:</label>
      <input type="text" id="pageTitle" placeholder="Page Title">
      <button onclick="createAccordion()">Create</button>
      <button onclick="closePopup()">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="accordion" class="accordion">
    <!-- Burada oluşturulan accordionlar eklenecek -->
  </div>
</div>




<div id="subPopup" class="sub-popup">
  <div class="sub-popup-content">
    <label for="subPageTitle">Sub Page Title:</label>
    <input type="text" id="subPageTitle" placeholder="Sub Page Title">
    <button onclick="createSubAccordion()">Create</button>
    <button onclick="closeSubPopup()">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="editPopup" class="edit-popup">
  <div class="edit-popup-content">
    <label for="frontContent">Front Content:</label>
    <input type="text" id="frontContent" placeholder="Front Content">
    <label for="backContent">Back Content:</label>
    <input type="text" id="backContent" placeholder="Back Content">
    <button onclick="updateFlashcardContent()">Update</button>
    <button onclick="closeEditPopup()">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please click [edit] and show expected HERE instead of on another site. If you have the code for how you WANT it to look, then why not copy that code?

Comment: So just show one at a time. It is not clear how to create the flash card, but the JS can hide previously created card when a new card is created

Comment: yes, I want the previously created card to be hidden when a new card is created.

Answer (score 0):

You have several things you need to do

1. Wrap the addFlashcard in a div so the plus and the next/prev is in a container

   ```
   const flashcardButtonNav = document.createElement("div");
   flashcardButtonNav.className = "flashcardnav";
   const flashcardEditButton = document.createElement("button");
   ...
   const flashcardPrev= document.createElement("button");
   ...
   const flashcardNext= document.createElement("button");
   ...
   flashcardButtonNav.appendChild(flashcardEditButton)
   flashcardButtonNav.appendChild(flashcardPrev);
   flashcardButtonNav.appendChild(flashcardNext);
   ```
2. Hide the last card

   ```
   const lastCard = flashcardContainer.querySelector('div.flashcard:last-of-type')
   if (lastCard) {
     lastCard.hidden = true;
     flashcardPrev.hidden = false; // toggle the flashcardNext and flashcardPrev in the navigation (prev.hidden if we are on the first card, next.hidden on the last card
   }
   flashcardContainer.insertBefore(flashcard, flashcardButtonNav);
   ```
3. DELEGATE.

   ```
    accordionContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const tgt = e.target.closest('button');
      currentFlashcardContainer = tgt.closest('div.flashcard-container');
      if (tgt.matches('.add-flashcard-button') {
         // add a flashcard
         return;
      }
      if (tgt.matches('.flashcardPrev') {
        // navigate

      }

    });
   ```